# Generate html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a gallery page that is updated often with new images. I use simple HTML to post the photos. My process currently is copy and paste the set of tags for a photo and change the number to correspond with the image file name. E.G. I change the number 047 to 048. Copy-Paste, change it to 049. This goes on until I have reached the number of additional photos. As you can see, this is very inefficient and there must be a better way of doing this. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve this with Javascript? Perhaps generate additional tags by inputing a certain number or range?

Any ideas that would make this process efficient are welcomed please! Thank you!

```
<div class="cbp-item trim">
          <a href="../assets/images/trim/img-trim-047.jpg" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox" data-title="">
              <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                  <img src="../assets/images/trim/img-trim-047.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you use server-side scripting (eg. PHP). If that is not possible, have a look at DOM in JavaScript. Alternatively, generate the HTML files automatically with a tool that is fairly easy to write.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a templating solution. There are several libraries for that, but you can also implement it yourself.

Here is one way to do that:

- Put the HTML for one image in a `script` tag that has a non-standard `language` property so the browser will just ignore it
- Put some keywords in there that you'll want to replace, e.g. `{url}`. You can invent your own syntax.
- Read that template into a variable
- In the JS code, put all the images' URLs in an array of strings
- For each element in that array, replace the keywords in the template string with that particular URL, and concatenate all these resulting HTML snippets.
- Inject the resulting HTML into the appropriate place in the document.

Here is a snippet doing that:

```js
// Add new images here:
var images = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/330px-SNice.svg.png",
    "https://nettemarie357.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/smiley-face.jpg?w=74&h=74",
];

// Load the template HTML
var template = document.querySelector('script[language="text/template"]').innerHTML;
// Use template to insert all the images:
container.innerHTML = images.map(url => template.replace(/{url}/g, url)).join('');
```

```css
img { max-width: 50px }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script language="text/template">
    <div class="cbp-item trim">
        <a href="{url}" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox" data-title="">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img src="{url}" alt="">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you creating it programatically:

```
var new_row = document.createElement('div');
new_row.className = "cbp-item trim";
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "../assets/images/trim/img-trim-047.jpg";
a.className= "cbp-caption cbp-lightbox";
document.body.appendChild(a);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "cbp-caption-defaultWrap";
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src= "../assets/images/trim/img-trim-047.jpg";
div.appendChild(img);
a.appendChild(div);
new_row.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about printing HTML, I suggest you to use plugins like [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/) for Sublime Text editor.

When you install this plugin and see how it works, you can simple create a complex html in a way that 'for' loop would do this. This will help you to change only the image/link number of every item.

Check the demo in the link, that I added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in Java Script that will generate the html you will need. Set the total to whatever number you need to generate the number of images you want.

```js
var total = 47;
var hook = document.getElementById('hook');

// Main Node for SlideShow
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.classList = "cbp-item trim";

// Work out the correct number 
var n = function(int) {
  var length = int.toString().length;
  return length === 1 
    ? '00' + int 
    : length === 2
      ? '0' + int
      : length
}

// Create the item
var createItem = function(int){

  // Create Anchor
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '../assets/images/trim/img-trim-' + ( n(int) ) + '.jpg" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox';
  a.classList = 'cbp-caption cbp-lightbox';

  // Create Div
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList = 'cbp-caption-defaultWrap';

  // Create Image
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = '../assets/images/trim/img-trim-' + ( n(int) ) + '.jpg';
  img.alt = 'gallery image';

  // Finalise Dom Node
  var container = div.appendChild(img)
  a.appendChild(div);
   
  // Return Final Item
  return a
  
}

// Create Items
for (var i = 1; i < total + 1; i++) {
  node.appendChild(createItem(i));
}

// Append Main Node to Hook
hook.appendChild(node);
```

```html
<div id="hook"></div>
```